# WPF MVVM How to pick up text changes on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, 2-way-object-databinding

I am working on a WPF project with MVVM and I encountered a problem of not picking up the last text change when I click the save button.

My components are setup like this:

1. A toolbar view with toolbar VM, which has the save button. button
   click event is bound to a Icommand.
2. A form view with a bunch of text fields, bound to a sepreate VM.
3. the toolbar view and form view are in seperate files.
4. all my VMs inherits from BindableBase (part of the Prism.MvvM package)

On button click, I will take the values from the form VM and save them... simple and stragight forward.
All is well, except that upon editing the last field, clicking the save button does not trigger the lose focus event. Therefore, the property Set event is not triggered. I will have to click away from the fields after editing then click on the button.
Here's my code:

```
 public class ViewModel: BindableBase
{
    private string _someText;

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return _someText; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _someText, value); }
    }
}
```

in the view XAML:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
```

in the toolbar XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" ToolTip="Save">
</Button>
```

ViewModel for the toolbar:

```
 public class ToolbarViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ICommand _saveCommand;
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveCommand ?? (_saveCommand = new BaseCommandHandler(() => { 
                //Save code
            }, () => true));
        }
    }
}
```

code for BaseCommandHandler:

```
 public class BaseCommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private Func<bool> _canExecute;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates instance of the command handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">Action to be executed by the command</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">A bolean property to containing current permissions to execute the command</param>
    public BaseCommandHandler(Action action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wires CanExecuteChanged event 
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Forcess checking if execute is allowed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute.Invoke();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a clean way to make sure focus is lost or a way to trigger the set event of the bindable properties

Comment: we need your code to help...

Comment: Could you show some code??

Comment: @DenisSchaf  code updated

Comment: @Jeffery Code Updated

Comment: I do not see the `ViewModel` and `ToolbarViewModel` communicating in any way. Thus it's possible that the `ToolbarViewModel` does not have any reference to the `SomeText` from the `ViewModel`. If it does, kindly show the code as well.

Comment: Are you saying that `SomeText` is not set as expected or what exactly is your issue here?

Comment: @mm8 yeah, upon clicking the save button the set of the SomeText property is not triggered. but if i click to another text box or simply clicking away on the view, the set is called

Comment: @Jeffery the ViewModel and ToolbarViewModel in this instance do not communicate. And I dont think we need them to communicate in anyways for the the lost focus to be triggered (unless this is where I went wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You should use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

`<TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: In fact, clicking a button means loss of focus for the textbox, so it _should_ have updated.

Comment: @Haukinger hmm...

Comment: @Haukinger, i thought that was the case, but sadly, no, it doesnt trigger the lose focus

Comment: @Haukinger, I wonder if it is because the toolbar and the text form are in seperate controls? which does not make sense though....

Comment: @JustanotherDev it could definitely be the source if the toolbar and form controls have individual view models.